# Can't use method of passed object in function

Tags: javascript, function, class, parameters, external

**What I have tried**

I have a thermostat program, that works perfectly fine, due to it being made with test driven development. I then wrote some code in my index's  area, to link my elements and buttons to the thermostat program, which all worked.

**What creates the problem**

The problem arises when I now want to put this in another js file, Linker.js. The code you see works fine if you remove the thermo.up(1) from Linker.js

Linker.js

```
function returnTemp(thermo) {
    thermo.up(1)
    console.log(thermo.temp)
}
```

Thermostat.js

```
static up(num) {
        this._tempChange(num);
        console.log(this.temp);
    };
```

Index.js

```
<!-- JS -->
<script src="src/Thermostat.js"></script>
<script src="src/Linker.js"></script>
<script>
    var stat = new Thermostat
</script>
```

Console

```
returnTemp(stat)
Uncaught TypeError: thermo.up is not a function
    at returnTemp (Linker.js:59)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(edited)
```

Comment: `static` methods don't have a `this` referencing an instance of the class.  A static method would be called like `Thermostat.up()`, not `instanceOfThermostat.up()`

Comment: Oh I see, I think. would I change the instance variables for the temperature to a class variable instead?

Comment: It depends on the scope that the variables should have.  If you want the ability to have instances of the class with their own values, you would not use static methods or variables.

Comment: I see. I will attempt to make the methods not static now, and report back if it fixes it.

Comment: It worked! I'm new to this javascript scope stuff. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I fixed it was how Taplar described.

My class for the Thermostat had class methods, not instance methods. Removing the static keyword for my methods fixed my problems.

Javascript Scope strikes again.

Comment: Just FWIW, class vs. prototype methods (instance methods are slightly different) has nothing to do with *scope*. Scope is about freestanding identifier resolution. Your issue was looking for a non-existent property on an object (because the property was on the constructor function, not the prototype the instance inherits from).